# Mapped Type with Prefix for each Property

Tags: typescript, template-literals, conditional-types, mapped-types

I would like to create a type that only allows properties that start with a given prefix like that:

```
const example = {
  '#prop1': () => {},
  '#prop2': () => {}
}
```

So each Property must be prefixed by a `#` in that case. I have played around with [»Template Literal Types«](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) within [»Mapped Types«](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) like so:

```
interface WithD {
  [s: `#${string}`]: () => void
}
```

But that yields this error:

> An index signature parameter type must be either 'string' or 'number'.

Is there any way to make that happen?

Comment: Mapped type assumes you have a type and map its properties to something else. `Record` would work with a union. But in both cases you need to have a limited number of options, I doubt TS would do regex on random properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Nadia Chibrikova said, there is no way to build `WithD` without knowing `example` value up front.

The only way to handle it -  is to know (be able to infer) the type you want to validate.

```js
type Validation<T extends Record<string, any>> = {
  [Prop in keyof T]: Prop extends `#${string}` ? T[Prop] : never
}

type Assert<T, U> = T extends U ? U extends T ? true : false : false


const example1 = {
  '#prop1': () => { },
  '#prop2': () => { },
}

const example2 = {
  ...example1,
  'prop3': () => { }
}

type Example1 = typeof example1;
type Example2 = typeof example2;


type Result1 = Assert<Example1, Validation<Example1>> // true
type Result2 = Assert<Example2, Validation<Example2>> // false


const isValid = <T extends Validation<T>>(arg: T) => { }
isValid(example1) // ok
isValid(example2) // expected error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAagQwDYEsAmCQoPYDsA8AKjFAB4hS5oDOMASlAMbYBOa%201ILKuA5gDQwEuMAD5RMALwwA3sBgwA2gAUW2CDB4wA1lDDYAZjEIBdAFwxV6kuUo0YAAwDEAEhmdufAL4OYAfmMVNQgTGAtcKAA3KBZgL2BQSFgAQWpqGJAiQQBVCWliMgoqWmz-GFLCu1piAK4AV1gLA2R0sJhmpHSE4GZcThsEAFsIJCgARilZeRgAcicIYLGZiwAKAEopCRkYL35puYX1ACZlmHXN2R29%20J68frIhkagjybkFADpPh%20HRsb2FGaHCAAZlO50kWx2cQS4GgMAAoqRHr9JrCoIYBj9xgBuRJwxHI56opIY75PI64mFJehQah1JAgCbSVLpFiZAlYv7wZDoTA4Agcp5jcQwAD0opg9SgeNgDDpDJezLSGXwgtGR0EiFQGCweFVSKxRxF4vaLWlCV6-RQ1C16EmRBsRXstp1-KI4hWCBYvAshA2EMu8WtLpWZN%20GxN2G0wGDPLQoYN5IjErI0EYFDQJBYahYQA)

Hence, TS should infer your type either from function argument or from type generic parameter

Comment: Thanks! Kind of sad to hear that it's not possible, but good to know as well ;)